# Foreign key misatch referencing

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-moor

i need your help please,
I'm creating a to-do app with flutter using moor as database,i've created three tables in my db,but only two are concerned by my problem they are ***tasks*** and ***projects***.Then when i try to insert a new task i got this error

> Exception has occurred. 
>   SqliteException (SqliteException: foreign key mismatch - "tasks" referencing "projects", SQL logic error)

There is my project table

```
class Projects extends Table {
     IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
     IntColumn get tasksNumber => integer()();
     TextColumn get projectName => text().withLength(min: 2, max: 32)();
     TextColumn get description => text().withLength(min: 2, max: 35)();
     DateTimeColumn get dateAndTime =>dateTime().withDefault(Constant(DateTime.now()))();
     BoolColumn get isCompleted => boolean().withDefault(Constant(false))();
     @override
     Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id, projectName};
}
```

And the task one is

```
class Tasks extends Table {
     IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
     TextColumn get project =>text().customConstraint('REFERENCES projects(projectName)')();
     TextColumn get taskName => text().withLength(min: 2, max: 32)();
     DateTimeColumn get dateAndTime =>dateTime().withDefault(Constant(DateTime.now()))();
     BoolColumn get isDone => boolean().withDefault(Constant(false))();
     @override
     Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id, taskName, project};
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it seems that the reason is that child table fk references to the non-pk column in the parent table.

In your case, if you change `'REFERENCES projects(projectName)'` to `'REFERENCES projects(id)'` the error will go. Or make `projectName` a pk.